# Weird undefined index errors

Tags: php

I have a few variables that are assigned the values of session variables (See the first four)--dbfunctions.php:

```
<?php 
    include_once('functions.php'); 

function newAdminCivilReport(){

$userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
$judge = $_SESSION['judgeID'];
$month = $_SESSION['month'];
$year = $_SESSION['year'];

$con = mysql_connect("-","-","-");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
else {
    // connected to database successfully
}
mysql_select_db("casemanagers", $con);
$PendingCivil = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PendingCivil']);
$PendingAsbestos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PendingAsbestos']);
$PendingDomestic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PendingDomestic']);
$AsgNewCivil = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgNewCivil']);
$AsgNewCivil = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgNewCivil']);
$AsgNewAsbestos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgNewAsbestos']);
$AsgNewDomestic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgNewDomestic']);
$AsgTransferCivil = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgTransferCivil']);
$AsgTransferAsbestos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgTransferAsbestos']);
$AsgTransferDomestic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgTransferDomestic']);
$AsgReopenedCivil = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgReopenedCivil']);
$AsgReopenedAsbestos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgReopenedAsbestos']);
$AsgReopenedDomestic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['AsgReopenedDomestic']);
$DispTOCivil = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DispTOCivil']);
$DispTOAsbestos = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DispTOAsbestos']);
$DispTODomestic = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DispTODomestic']);
$clerkITNumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['clerkITNumber']);


$query = "INSERT INTO `casemanagers`.`civil` (`JudgeID`, `Month`, `Year`, `PendingCivil`, `PendingAsbestos`, `PendingDomestic`, `AsgNewCivil`, `AsgNewAsbestos`, `AsgNewDomestic`, `AsgTransferCivil`, `AsgTransferAsbestos`, `AsgTransferDomestic`, `AsgReopenedCivil`, `AsgReopenedAsbestos`, `AsgReopenedDomestic`, `DispWOPCivil`, `DispWOPAsbestos`, `DispWOPDomestic`, `DispFinalCivil`, `DispFinalAsbestos`, `DispFinalDomestic`, `DispBTCivil`, `DispBTAsbestos`, `DispBTDomestic`, `DispJTCivil`, `DispJTAsbestos`, `DispJTDomestic`, `DispTOCivil`, `DispTOAsbestos`, `DispTODomestic`, `OldCivil`, `OldAsbestos`, `OldDomestic`, `userID`, `clerkITNumber`) VALUES ($judge, $month, $year, $PendingCivil, $PendingAsbestos, $PendingDomestic, $AsgNewCivil, $AsgNewAsbestos, $AsgNewDomestic, $AsgTransferCivil, $AsgTransferAsbestos, $AsgTransferDomestic, $AsgReopenedCivil, $AsgReopenedAsbestos, $AsgReopenedDomestic, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, $DispTOCivil, $DispTOAsbestos, $DispTODomestic, 0, 0, 0, $userId, $clerkITNumber);";
mysql_select_db("casemanagers", $con);

$result = mysql_query($query);
return $result;
mysql_close($con);
}
?>
```

These values are in a function in a separate file. When I use the function (which inserts a whole bunch of items in a database), everything, including the proper values for the variables above, gets inserted into the database successfully. However, I'm still getting:

**Notice: Undefined index: judgeID in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CaseManagement\dbfunctions.php on line 6**

**Notice: Undefined index: month in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CaseManagement\dbfunctions.php on line 7**

**Notice: Undefined index: year in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CaseManagement\dbfunctions.php on line 8**

I can't figure out why. The variables work as they should.

main.php:

```
<?php


session_start();

   include_once('dbfunctions.php');
   include_once('functions.php');
    $result = newAdminCivilReport();

?>
```

Comment: Not enough code.

Comment: Show us the first 10 lines of c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CaseManagement\dbfunctions.php

Comment: @Tim H: This is the beginning of c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CaseManagement\dbfunctions.php ? (Just making sure.) You've posted specific errors referencing specific lines in a specific file. We just need to see that file (or the first 10 lines, since the last error is on line 8).

Comment: @Tim H: You've still not shown us the first 10 lines of `dbfunctions.php` have you?

Comment: @Tim H We still don't see where in the code those `$_SESSION` vars are originally set.

Comment: @Tim H Where (in which file) are the statements like `$_SESSION['year'] = $someyear;` ? If those statements aren't happening, that's the reason for your undefined indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`session_start()` must be the *very* first thing in your PHP. So it needs to be:

```
<?php
   session_start(); // <=== this MUST be first
   include_once('dbfunctions.php');
   include_once('functions.php');

    $result = newAdminCivilReport();

?>
```

EDIT:
Variables in PHP functions are local unless declared otherwise, so make the following change to `dbfunctions.php`:

```
function newAdminCivilReport(){
    global $_SESSION; // <==== add this line at the start
```

Comment: @Tim H: Please show us the first 10 lines of `dbfunctions.php`.

Comment: The only thing i left off: <?php
 include_once('functions.php');

Comment: @Tim H: No, the file *containing* the text `include_once('dbfunctions.php');` and `include_once('functions.php');` is *not* the file we're looking for. We want the file *named* `dbfunctions.php`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `session_start()` called here before accessing the `$_SESSION` variables.

Comment: And even if the session was started, maybe the keys are not set…

Comment: But if that's the case, why wouldn't he also be getting an error on the `'userId'` index? I'm guessing we're not seeing all, and `session_start()` is somewhere higher up.

Comment: @Jonathan we can't see it, but it's possible that `userId` is assigned to `$_SESSION` further up without having called `session_start()`. It would remain a valid key though it wouldn't persist across a page load.

Comment: @Michael - yep. need to see more.

Comment: @Tim H: Please see the comments under your original post. They tell what we need to see.